# Regular expression to match comma separated list of key=value where value can contain commas

Tags: python, regex, parsing, python-2.6

I have a naive "parser" that simply does something like:
`[x.split('=') for x in mystring.split(',')]`

However mystring can be something like
`'foo=bar,breakfast=spam,eggs'`

Obviously,
The naive splitter will just not do it. I am limited to **Python 2.6 standard library** for this,
So for example [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) can not be used.

Expected output is
`[('foo', 'bar'), ('breakfast', 'spam,eggs')]`

I'm trying to do this with regex, but am facing the following problems:

My First attempt
`r'([a-z_]+)=(.+),?'`
Gave me
`[('foo', 'bar,breakfast=spam,eggs')]`

Obviously,
Making `.+` non-greedy does not solve the problem.

So,
I'm guessing I have to somehow make the last comma (or `$`) mandatory.
Doing just that does not really work,
`r'([a-z_]+)=(.+?)(?:,|$)'`
As with that the stuff behind the comma in an value containing one is omitted,
e.g. `[('foo', 'bar'), ('breakfast', 'spam')]`

I think I must use some sort of look-behind(?) operation.
**The Question(s)**
1. **Which one** do I use? or
2. **How** do I do that/this?

**Edit**:

Based on [daramarak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/86638/daramarak)'s answer below,
I ended up doing pretty much the same thing as [abarnert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/908494/abarnert) later [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14642123/180174) in a slightly more verbose form;

```
vals = [x.rsplit(',', 1) for x in (data.split('='))]
ret = list()
while vals:
    value = vals.pop()[0]
    key = vals[-1].pop()
    ret.append((key, value))
    if len(vals[-1]) == 0:
        break
```

**EDIT 2:**

Just to satisfy my curiosity, is this actually possible with *pure* regular expressions? I.e so that `re.findall()` would return a list of 2-tuples?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Why don't just use semicolon (foo=bar;breakfast=spam,eggs) ?

Comment: @RohitJain key is to the left of `=`and value to the right. And immediately to the left of a `=`is always a key. new key-value pairs are also separated using commas. Right OP?

Comment: `mystring.split(',').split('=')`? apply `.split('=')` to a `list` object?

Comment: @OscarMederos right, that wasn't the actual code as it is a bit more messy. I'll fix it.

Comment: @user1307957 I'm "parsing" something that is given. doing a `mystring.replace(',', ';')` does not really help me at all - if I knew which commas to replace, I already would have parsed the input...

Comment: @Kimvais What is your expected output?

Comment: @OscarMederos - Edited question to include the expected output

Comment: +1 for a good question that explains what you're actually trying to do, and what you've tried, instead of just asking "How do I make this regex work".

Comment: @Kimvais: You didn't use my regex correctly. Hence it doesn't work.

Comment: Ahhhh, I though this solved my problem but sometimes the value contains `html` and that contains all sorts of character `=`, `;`, `:`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just for comparison purposes, here's a regex that seems to solve the problem as well:

```
([^=]+)    # key
=          # equals is how we tokenise the original string
([^=]+)    # value
(?:,|$)    # value terminator, either comma or end of string
```

The trick here it to restrict what you're capturing in your second group. `.+` swallows the `=` sign, which is the character we can use to distinguish keys from values. The full regex doesn't rely on any back-tracking (so it should be compatible with something like [re2](http://code.google.com/p/re2/), if that's desirable) and can work on abarnert's examples.

Usage as follows:

```
re.findall(r'([^=]+)=([^=]+)(?:,|$)', 'foo=bar,breakfast=spam,eggs,blt=bacon,lettuce,tomato,spam=spam')
```

Which returns:

```
[('foo', 'bar'), ('breakfast', 'spam,eggs'), ('blt', 'bacon,lettuce,tomato'), ('spam', 'spam')]
```

Comment: Actually, for once I have to say that the regular expression method is much easier to read than the other way of doing things. Awesome! +1

Answer (score 4):

daramarak's answer either very nearly works, or works as-is; it's hard to tell from the way the sample output is formatted and the vague descriptions of the steps. But if it's the very-nearly-works version, it's easy to fix.

Putting it into code:

```
>>> bits=[x.rsplit(',', 1) for x in s.split('=')]
>>> kv = [(bits[i][-1], bits[i+1][0]) for i in range(len(bits)-1)]
```

The first line is (I believe) daramarak's answer. By itself, the first line gives you pairs of `(value_i, key_i+1)` instead of `(key_i, value_i)`. The second line is the most obvious fix for that. With more intermediate steps, and a bit of output, to see how it works:

```
>>> s = 'foo=bar,breakfast=spam,eggs,blt=bacon,lettuce,tomato,spam=spam'
>>> bits0 = s.split('=')
>>> bits0
['foo', 'bar,breakfast', 'spam,eggs,blt', 'bacon,lettuce,tomato,spam', 'spam']
>>> bits = [x.rsplit(',', 1) for x in bits0]
>>> bits
[('foo'), ('bar', 'breakfast'), ('spam,eggs', 'blt'), ('bacon,lettuce,tomato', 'spam'), ('spam')]
>>> kv = [(bits[i][-1], bits[i+1][0]) for i in range(len(bits)-1)]
>>> kv
[('foo', 'bar'), ('breakfast', 'spam,eggs'), ('blt', 'bacon,lettuce,tomato'), ('spam', 'spam')]
```

Comment: Clarified my answer to show my meaning. But you manage to flatten the structure and pair it in one go. That is +1 from me.

Answer (score 1):

Could I suggest that you use the split operations as before. But split at the equals first, then splitting at the rightmost comma, to make a single list of left and right strings.

```
input =
"bob=whatever,king=kong,banana=herb,good,yellow,thorn=hurts"
```

will at first split become

```
first_split = input.split("=")
#first_split = ['bob' 'whatever,king' 'kong,banana' 'herb,good,yellow,thorn' 'hurts']
```

then splitting at rightmost comma gives you:

```
second_split = [single_word for sublist in first_split for item in sublist.rsplit(",",1)]
#second_split = ['bob' 'whatever' 'king' 'kong' 'banana' 'herb,good,yellow' 'thorn' 'hurts']
```

then you just gather the pairs like this:

```
pairs = dict(zip(second_split[::2],second_split[1::2]))
```

Comment: I think that this _could_ work, but how exactly would you _just gather the pairs_ so that it works for all inputs?

Comment: This would be much easier to read with separators in the example output. It's hard to tell from `bob whatever king kong banana…` that `bob` is a key, `whatever` is a value, etc. If I understand what you're doing, the last step will not work, because you're actually going to have `(value_n, key_n+1)` pairs, not `(key_n, value_n)` pairs. But it's close. See my answer.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this, I don't think it deserved it. It's a bit vague, but the approach is pretty clearly right, and it's just missing the last step, which would be obvious once you printed out the results.

Comment: I have been vague here in purpose, I do not think writing the code would be necessary here. It seemed clear to me that OP would be able to do the programming, I simply wanted wanted OP to look at the problem in another way.

Comment: Ah, now I get what you were doing. The problem with the original version was that, without showing the commas or quotes or any other way to tell where the boundaries were, it was ambiguous. Anyway, flattening it out and then rezipping as you did is possibly clearer than the `(x[i][-1], x[i+1][0])` bit I did, even if it does seem like an extra step.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this, it worked for me:

```
mystring = "foo=bar,breakfast=spam,eggs,e=a"
n = []
i = 0

for x in mystring.split(','):
    if '=' not in x:
        n[i-1] = "{0},{1}".format(n[i-1], x)
    else:
        n.append(x)
        i += 1
print n
```

You get result like:

```
  ['foo=bar', 'breakfast=spam,eggs', 'e=a']
```

Then you can simply go over list and do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the name of the key never contains `,`, you can split at `,` when the next sequence without `,` and `=` is succeeded by `=`.

```
re.split(r',(?=[^,=]+=)', inputString)
```

(This is the same as my original solution. I expect `re.split` to be used, rather than `re.findall` or `str.split`).

The full solution can be done in one-liner:

```
[re.findall('(.*?)=(.*)', token)[0] for token in re.split(r',(?=[^,=]+=)', inputString)]
```