# Regex to parse "a=1,b=2,c=3,4,5,d=6,e=x,y,z"

Tags: c#, regex

How can I use a regex to split (or match) this string:

```
a=1,b=2,c=3,4,5,d=6,e=x,y,z
```

The basic form is `name=value,name=value` where value could contain commas and name is always alphanumeric.

I'm trying to end up with:

```
a=1
b=2
c=3,4,5
d=6
e=x,y,z
```

My first thought was that the grammar was ambiguous since the values contain commas, but I think it should be doable since name doesn't contain `=`.

This is close, but matches the trailing comma to each value and doesn't match the final `z`:

```
(?<name>\w+)
\s*=\s*
(?<value>
\S
   (?:
      ,
      |
      .[^=]         
    )*
)
```

Produces these matches:

```
a=1,
b=2,
c=3,4,5,  
d=6,
e=x,y,
```

Any regex wizards on here?

Comment: Seems to be python - guessing from (?<name>...

Comment: C# but wouldn't want a pattern when it would matter.

Comment: Can you prepend a comma? Would probably make the regex simpler.

Comment: This basically duplicate [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14644737/274466) where the same regex appears to work. See [this RegexPlanet sample](http://fiddle.re/zw4u). Expression used is just `([^=]+)=([^=]+)(?:,|$)` (not too dissimilar from yours).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just split on `comma` which is followed by an `alphabet` and then `=`, using a *look-ahead assertion*. You can use the below regex for split: -

```
",(?=[a-zA-Z0-9]=)");
```

Comment: I thought I knew regex pretty well, but I've never used "?=" - This is perfect - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In your final match with `,|.[^=]` the `.[^=]` means any character followed by a character that is not `=`.  However, `z` is followed by nothing.  Instead, you should make it any character followed by not `=` OR the end of the string:

```
,
|
.(?:[^=]|$)
```

I have confirmed that this works using php's `preg_match_all`.

Answer (score 0):

If your regular expression engine support [lookahead assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) you can try this :

```
(\w)=(\w(,\w(?!=))*)
```

Note : I used `\w` to make it shorter. If you only want to match only alphanumeric characters replace `\w` instead of `[a-zA-Z0-9]`

Works successfully on [regexpal](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%5Cw=%28%5Cw%28,%5Cw%28?!=%29%29%2a%29&input=a=1,b=2,c=3,4,5,d=6,e=x,y,z,d=4,4,3)

EDIT : busted by Rohit Jain