# Regex for key value pair where separator characters can be embedded in the value (Scala)

Tags: java, regex, parsing, scala

I'm trying to use a regexp to parse a string of the form:

"a=10:30:00:b=2:c=3"

to yield

```
a=10:30:00
b=2
c=3
```

The closest i've gotten is 
    (\w+)=(\S+?)(?=:|$), 
but that chops off a's :30:00:

```
a=10
b=2
c=3
```

Code is in scala:

```
scala> val s = "a=10:20:00:b=2:c=3"
s: java.lang.String = a=10:20:00:b=2:c=3

scala> val R = """(\w+)=(\S+?)(?=:|$)""".r 
R: scala.util.matching.Regex = (\w+)=(\S+?)(?=:|$)

scala> R findAllIn s foreach println
a=10
b=2
c=3
```

### Edit

Modified the regex based on 
[Regular expression to match comma separated list of key=value where value can contain commas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14641750/regular-expression-to-match-comma-separated-list-of-key-value-where-value-can-co?rq=1) to handle:

```
val s = "foo=bar:baz:r=abc:a=10:20:00:b=2:c=3:s=xx:yy:z=100"

val R = """([^=]+)=([^=]+)(?::|$)""".r

R findAllMatchIn s foreach { x => println(x.subgroups) }
                                              //> List(foo, bar:baz)
                                              //| List(r, abc)
                                              //| List(a, 10:20:00)
                                              //| List(b, 2)
                                              //| List(c, 3)
                                              //| List(s, xx:yy)
                                              //| List(z, 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
scala> val R = """(\w+)=(\d+(?::\d+)*)""".r
R: scala.util.matching.Regex = (\w+)=(\d+(?::\d+)*)

scala> for(R(key, value) <- R.findAllIn(str)) println(key + "=" + value)
a=10:30:00
b=2
c=3
```

Or based the regex you quoted:

```
scala> val R = """([^:=]+)=([^=]+)(?=:|$)""".r
R: scala.util.matching.Regex = (\w+)=([^=]+)(?=:|$)

scala> for(R(key, value) <- R.findAllIn(str)) println(key + "=" + value)
a=10:30:00
b=2
c=3
```