# Regular expression to match comma separated list of key=value where value can contain html?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match a comma seperated list of key=value where the value can contain well a while host of things quite frankly.

The pattern I am using is exactly from this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14641750/regular-expression-to-match-comma-separated-list-of-key-value-where-value-can-co):

`split_up_pattern = re.compile(r'([^=]+)=([^=]+)(?:,|$)', re.X|re.M)`

However it is causing issues when the value contains html.

Here is an example script:

```
import re

text = '''package_contents=<p>The basic Super&nbsp;1050 machine includes the following:</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<table style="" height: 567px;"" border=""1"">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style=""width: 200px;"">
<ul>
<li>uper 1150 machine</li>
</ul>
</td>
<td>&nbsp;With dies fitted.
<ul>
<li>The Super 1050</li>
</ul>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
<table>,second_attribute=something else'''

split_up_pattern = re.compile(r'([\w_^=]+)=([^=]+)(?:,|$)', re.X|re.M)

matches = split_up_pattern.findall(text)

import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()

print(matches)
```

The output:

```
ipdb> matches[0]
('package_contents', '<p>The basic Super&nbsp;1050 machine includes the following:</p>\n\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\n')
ipdb> matches[1]
('border', '""1"">\n\n<tbody>\n\n<tr>\n')
ipdb> matches[2]
('style', '""width: 200px;"">\n\n<ul>\n\n<li>uper 1150 machine</li>\n\n</ul>\n\n</td>\n\n<td>&nbsp;With dies fitted.\n\n<ul>\n\n<li>The Super 1050</li>\n\n</ul>\n\n</td>\n\n</tr>\n</tbody>\n<table>')
ipdb> matches[3]
('second_attribute', 'something else')
```

The output I want is:

`matches[0]`:

```
('package_contents', '<p>The basic Super&nbsp;1050 machine includes the following:</p><p>&nbsp;</p><table style="" height: 567px;"" border=""1""><tbody><tr><td style=""width: 200px;""><ul><li>uper 1150 machine</li></ul></td><td>&nbsp;With dies fitted.<ul><li>The Super 1050</li></ul></td></tr>
</tbody><table>',)
```

`matches[1]`:

```
('second_attribute', 'something else')
```

Comment: This is a tough one, how are you getting this data in the first place? Any way for you to tokenize it at source? If there is no guarantee that the delimiter won't occur inside the values, all bets on parsing by regular expressions (and most other methods actually) are off. You need to find a delimiter that will *never* occur in the values.

Comment: You are using the `re.M` flag for multi-line regular expression. I suspect this is an error.

Comment: If a comma does not ever appear anywhere in your HTML, then changing your search to `split_up_pattern = re.compile(r'([^=]+)=([^,]+)(?:,|$)')` should work.

Comment: @Phylogenesis Unfortunately a comma does appear.

Comment: @ffledgling I am exporting from an ecommerce website. So the output is in `csv` format. One column however merges all the `additional_attributes` as shown above

Comment: If your keys only contain word characters and are directly preceded by a comma, you can try this: `(?:^|,)(\w+)=(.*?)(?=$|,\w+=)`

Comment: @surfer190 can you export it in a different format? Excel perhaps? You can then use an excel parser in python to parse the data and create a proper dictionary/dataframe of the data instead of having to write a regex that will always break because the content might have a `,` in it.

Comment: You must know all possible keys before `=`, or at least how to define the value end boundary. Else, there is no solution.

Comment: My mistake. I added a second attribute to show that subsequent attribute will always be of the form `,<non-breaking word or underscore>=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of basing the parsing narrowly on the delimiters (comma or equal sign), you can leverage the fact that the next key-value pair starts with something like this:

```
,WORD=
```

Here's a sketch of the idea:

```
import re

text = '''...your example...'''

# Start of the string or our ,WORD= pattern.
rgx_spans = re.compile(r'(\A|,)\w+=')

# Get the start-end positions of all matches.
spans = [m.span() for m in rgx_spans.finditer(text)]

# Use those positions to break up the string into parsable chunks.
for i, s1 in enumerate(spans):
    try:
        s2 = spans[i + 1]
    except IndexError:
        s2 = (None, None)

    start = s1[0]
    end = s2[0]
    key, val = text[start:end].lstrip(',').split('=', 1)

    print()
    print(s1, s2)
    print((key, val))
```